# Swapping out HTML with Javascript onClick, having to refresh to see change

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, sessionstorage

I am setting up a geo search bar on the sidebar of my website. When the user clicks a link to allow geo location, I am trying to display their zipcode in the header of the sidebar. This works fine, but upon initial click, you have to refresh the page in order for the zip code to appear.

The way I have it set up currently, it returns "Undefined" on click and then on refresh it shows the correct zip. I'm assuming I have to set up some sort of wait function or something so that the function that replaces the header text doesn't fire until a zip code is defined.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's the javascript:

```
// Set sessionStorage paramater on click
$('#findLocations').click(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html",
      url: "/search/georesults.html",
      success: function(closestLocation) {
        jQuery('.result').html(closestLocation);
      } // end success
    }); // end ajax
    $('.resultHeader').html('Stores nearest <div class="zip">' + userZip + '</div>');
    sessionStorage.UseIP = "Yes"
});

// Check for UseIP and display nearest locations if set
if ( sessionStorage.UseIP == "Yes" ){
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html",
      url: "/search/georesults.html",
      success: function(closestLocation) {
        jQuery('.result').html(closestLocation);
      } // end success
    }); // end ajax
    $('.resultHeader').html('Stores nearest <div class="zip">' + userZip + '</div>');
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you mixing jQuery('.result') and $('.resultHeader') syntax?  There very well could be a good reason I'm missing.

Comment: .resultHeader is the class of the H4 tag I am appending the zip code to, .result is the area where the actual results are displayed. Maybe I should just replace all the HTML within the div instead of 2 separate locations?

Comment: I was talking about the JQuery call itself, not the elements in question.  You can use "JQuery." or "$." they both mean the same thing.  Just looks strange mixed (at least to me).

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now, ya it's a bad habbit of mine. I'm still pretty new to jQuery and I've been working with Wordpress a lot and it's a compatibility thing with Wordpress, sometimes I mix them when I'm coding, especially if I'm borrowing code from previous wordpress projects. Anyhow, thanks again for the fix, appreciate it!

Comment: I honestly do the same thing, that's why I noticed.  Most JQuery I "write" is copied from somewhere.  I know how it works and what things do, but I'm terrible at remembering the exact syntax for it sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the result header changes into the same success callback like this:

```
// Set sessionStorage paramater on click
$('#findLocations').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html",
      url: "/search/georesults.html",
      success: function(closestRep) {
        $('.result').html(closestRep);
        $('.resultHeader').html('Stores nearest <div class="zip">' + userZip + '</div>');
      } // end success
    }); // end ajax

    sessionStorage.UseIP = "Yes"
});

// Check for UseIP and display nearest locations if set
if ( sessionStorage.UseIP == "Yes" ){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html",
      url: "/search/georesults.html",
      success: function(closestLocation) {
        $('.result').html(closestLocation);
        $('.resultHeader').html('Stores nearest <div class="zip">' + userZip + '</div>');
      } // end success
    }); // end ajax

}
```

Note, it might be worth-while to add a separate function for changing both at the same time.  You can use that as your callback and avoid 2 sections of code to maintain.

Comment: Aha! Hadn't even thought of that, giving it a try now.

Comment: It's one of those things you need to take a step away from to see it.  You answered it yourself: "I'm assuming I have to set up some sort of wait function or something so that the function that replaces the header text doesn't fire until a zip code is defined." - That's exactly what the callback is for.